# Android animating ImageViews within a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Hi i have a view pager that loads fragments and i'm wanting to add a bit of animation to an ImageView make it move up as the ViewPager scrolls. problem i'm having is that the viewPager creates the views for the first two pages so the animation doesnt happen on those pages. Is there is a way to detect if viewpager is scrolling or if the page has changed?

heres what i have tried so far - heres my viewPagerAdapter

```
 @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {



            if(page == 0){
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_tutorial, container, false);    
            }else if(page == 1){
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_tutorial, container, false);


                tutImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.tutImage);
                int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("tut_view_2", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
                Drawable tutImageDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    tutImage.setBackground(tutImageDrawable);
                }else{
                    tutImage.setBackgroundDrawable(tutImageDrawable);
                }

            }else if(page == 2){
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_tutorial, container, false);



                tutImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.tutImage);
                int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("tut_view_3", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
                Drawable tutImageDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    tutImage.setBackground(tutImageDrawable);
                }else{
                    tutImage.setBackgroundDrawable(tutImageDrawable);
                }
```

heres my viewpager

```
 public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

            private Context context;

            public MyPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager,Context c) {

                super(fragmentManager);
                context = c;
            }


            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                int levelCount = 4;


                return levelCount;
            }

            // Returns the fragment to display for that page
            @Override
            public TutorialAdapter getItem(int position) {
                String data = null;

                return TutorialAdapter.newInstance(position, data, context);

            }


            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return "Page " + position;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a OnPageChangeListener, set it to your viewpager:

```
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(myOnPageChangeListener);
```

The OnPageChangeListener implements some methods like:

```
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {}
```

They can help you. Check this for more information: [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html)!